# How to create a new list from a previous list where elements are added to their position if the position is even?

Tags: python

Define a function named addPosToElem(...)  which receives a list with integer numbers and returns a new list containing the elements form the original list in even positions where the position is added to the element. The list can possibly be empty

As an example, the following code fragment:

```
lst = [0,10,20,30,40,50]
print(addPosToElem(lst))

gives the output:
[0, 22, 44]
```

My code:

```
def addPosToElem(lst):
    for i in range(lst[0], len(lst)):
        if (lst[i] % 2) == 1:
            element_odd = int(lst[i])
        elif (lst[i] % 2) == 0:
            element_even = int(lst[i]) + lst.index(i)
        new_lst = element_odd + element_even


    return new_lst
```

I keep getting 1 is not in list, how to fix my code?

Comment: instead of checking `lst[i] % 2` you should probably check `i % 2` because `i` is the index (which should be even) whereas `lst[i]` is the actual value at that index.

Comment: It shows list index out of range

Comment: Also, you are using `lst.index(i)` which looks for `i` in the list and `i` is not in your list as the error states.

Comment: You are doing a range between the value of the first element and the length. Try `range(len(lst)`.

Answer (score 4):

The most pythonic way to do this is with `list comprehension`:

```
[num + place for place, num in enumerate(lst) if place % 2 == 0]
# [0, 22, 44]
```

Or with regular loop:

```
new_lst = []
for place in range(len(lst)):
    if place % 2 == 0:
        new_lst.append(lst[place] + place)
new_lst # [0, 22, 44]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want. It isn't as 'good' as list comprehension but may be slightly more readable for a beginner.

```
def addPosToElem(lst):
    new_lst = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if (i % 2) == 0:
            new_lst.append(lst[i] + i)
    return new_lst
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few error with this approach:

1. As mentioned in the comment, you are checking `lst[i]%2`, you should check `i%2` to get the indices.
2. You are checking `lst.index(i)` which fails in the 2nd iteration, because `i` is `1` and `1` is not in list.
3. You are not using the `element_odd` and `element_odd` as lists, so even if somehow your algorithm worked you would get two values as output.

Instead try this:

```
def addPosToElem(lst):
    return [index+value for index, value in enumerate(lst) if index%2 == 0]
```

Your fixed code will be:

```
def addPosToElem(lst):
    new_lst = []
    for i in range(lst[0], len(lst)):
        if (i % 2) == 0:
            element_even = int(lst[i]) + i
            new_lst.append(element_even)
    return new_lst
```